# cmake link shared and static library individually

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, linker, g++

I am using CMake to build my C++ project. My project needs to link `main.cpp` with shared libraries and static libraries. For example,

Static libraries: `libstatic1`, and `libstatic2`.
Shared libraries: `libshared1`, and `libshared2`.

The solution for `g++` command is:

```
g++ -O0 -g main.o -Wl,-Bdynamic libshared1 libshared2 -Wl,-Bstatic libstatic1 libstatic2
```

By setting the linker options `-Bdynamic` and `-Bstatic` for shared libs and static libs respectively, `main.p` will be able to link with these libs correctly.

I don't know how to do it using CMake.

I set `target_link_options(proj PUBLIC "LINKER:-Bstatic")` and `target_link_options(proj PUBLIC "LINKER:-Bshared")` as below:

```
//CMakeLists.txt
project(proj)

#settings
...
...

add_executable(proj main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(proj libshared1 libshared2)
target_link_options(proj PUBLIC "LINKER:-Bdynamic")

target_link_libraries(proj libstatic1 libstatic2)
target_link_options(proj PUBLIC "LINKER:-Bstatic")
```

I checked the g++ command by using `make VERBOSE=1`, it doesn't behave as I expect.

So the question is:
How to use CMake to set such g++ flags?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you need this ?

Can't you use something like this ?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(proj)
...
add_library(shared1 SHARED ...)
add_library(shared2 SHARED ...)

add_library(static1 STATIC ...)
add_library(static2 STATIC ...)
...

add_executable(proj main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(proj PRIVATE shared1 shared2 static1 static2)
```